# Rapid 7 Export Windows Devices to CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to export Windows devices to a CSV from Rapid 7 using the API and Ruby.

When I run the below script it is throwing an error about:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'each' for #<Nexpose::AdhocReportConfig:0x000000
029bf4b8>
        from (irb):232:in block in irb_binding
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/csv.rb:1299:in 'open'
        from (irb):231
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/irb.cmd:19:in '<main>'
```

The code that I'm running is:

```
require 'nexpose'
require 'csv'

include Nexpose

query = "
SELECT da.host_name AS Name, dos.description AS OS
FROM dim_asset da 
   JOIN dim_operating_system dos USING (operating_system_id) 
   JOIN dim_host_type dht USING (host_type_id) 
   JOIN dim_site_asset dsa USING (asset_id) 
   JOIN dim_site ds USING (site_id)
Where (dos.description LIKE '%Windows%' AND da.host_name IS NOT NULL)"

@nsc = Connection.new('192.168.0.1', 'user', 'pswd')
@nsc.login

report = Nexpose::AdhocReportConfig.new(nil, 'sql')
report.add_filter('version', '1.1.0')
report.add_filter('query', query)

@nsc.logout

headers = ["Name","OS"] 

CSV.open('C:\file.csv', 'wb', { force_quotes: true }) do |csv|
  report.each do |reports| 
    if csv.tell() == 0  # file is empty, so write header
       csv << headers
    end
    csv << [report.Name, report.OS]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call `.each` on an instance of `Nexpose::AdhocReportConfig`

Try something like this:

```
report = Nexpose::AdhocReportConfig.new(nil, 'sql')  
report.add_filter('version', '1.1.0')  
report.add_filter('query', query)
report_output = report.generate(@nsc)
...
CSV.open('C:\file.csv', 'wb', { force_quotes: true }) do |csv|
  report_output.each do |reports|
...
```

See a full example here: https://community.rapid7.com/docs/DOC-2733